# Formulario en blanco. No funciona

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

he creado el siguiente formulario y quiero que los datos introducidos se guarden en la base de datos. Pero cuando envío el formulario, se queda en blanco y no hace nada.

He creado la base de datos, el usuario y la tabla. Todos los datos son correctos:

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario De Contacto</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
                <p>Nombre</p>
                <label for="nombre">Su nombre</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="user" required>
                <p>Correo</p>
                <label for="correo">Direccion De Correo</label>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="pass" required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**guardar.php**

```
<?php
//conectamos Con el servidor
$conectar=@mysql_connect('localhost','Usuario','Contraseña');
//verificamos la conexion
if(!$conectar){
    echo"No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor";
}else{

    $base=mysql_select_db('NombreBaseDeDatos');
    if(!$base){
        echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";          
    }
}
//recuperar las variables
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
//hacemos la sentencia de sql
$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$user',
                               '$pass')";
//ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);
//verificamos la ejecucion
if(!$ejecutar){
    echo"Hubo Algun Error";
}else{
    echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
}
?>
```

- Donde pongo "Usuario" he colocado el usuario creado, "Contraseña" es la contraseña de ese usuario y "NombreDeBaseDatos" es la base de datos en sí.
- El usuario está añadido a la base de datos con todos los privilegios.

Comment: De acuerdo a [esta referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) **mysql_connect**  fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. Igual y por ahí está el detalle dependiendo de la versión de php que estas usando.

Answer (score 0):

estás realizando mal la conexión a la base de datos. En primer lugar cabe destacar que las funciones `mysql` se están reemplazando por las `mysqli` en la versiones nuevas de PHP, así que tendrías que intentar migrar a estas nuevas funciones.
También hay algunos errores de concatenamiento en la consulta y falta asignar el nombre de las columnas donde se guardará cada dato.
Además, deberías hacer algún tipo de validación de las variables recibidas por `$_POST`, ya que de esta forma es muy inseguro y puede prestarse a una inyección SQL.

Acá te dejo de ejemplo tu código actualizado y corregido:

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $conectar = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");

    //verificamos la conexion
    if($conectar->connect_errno){
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conectar->connect_errno . ") " . $conectar->connect_error;
    }

    //recuperar las variables
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //hacemos la sentencia de sql
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pruebas (user, pass) VALUES('".$user."', '".$pass.".')";

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $resultado = $conectar->query($sql);

    //verificamos la ejecucion
    if(!($resultado)){
        echo"Hubo Algun Error(" . $conectar->errno . ") " . $conectar->error;
    }else{
        $conectar->close();
        echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
    }
?>
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: de hecho el uso de las comillas simples al momento de pasar las variables al INSERT como lo tiene el OP es correcto y válido

Comment: no, la sintáxis también asi es válida para insertar un registro

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron en el comentario estás usando instrucciones que han sido declaradas obsoletas [Ver referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Te recomiendo cambiar de `mysql_connect` a `mysqli_connect`  [Aquí la referencia de esta función](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php), por lo tanto tu cadena de conexión quedaría así:

```
$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Usuario", "Contraseña", "NombreBaseDeDatos");

if (!$conectar) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

y ejecutas tu consulta de esta manera:

```
//recuperar las variables
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
//hacemos la sentencia de sql
$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$user', '$pass')";

if (mysqli_query($conectar, $sql)) {
    echo "Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conectar);
}
```

Veo que no estas especificando los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla, por lo tanto asegúrate de que el orden de los valores esté en el mismo orden que las columnas de la tabla. Si no mejor usa la instruccion:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: pero si el problema fuera la conexión, no le debería aparecer un warning avisandole que ese modo de conexión esta obsoleto?

Comment: Debería, pero en las `echo` que imprime (Post original) no concatena las cadenas que impriman los errores que puedan surgir.